# How to use Ruby on Rails 3.2 Action Mailer with Gmail without turning unsecure device attributes on?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, gmail, actionmailer

Is there anyway to use action mailer without turning the unsecure device gmail attribute on? I don't want to expose my email account to the world by turning the unsecure option on for my ruby on rails app.

Is there a way to enter the username and password for such an email system without assigning the username and passwords directly to the application environment of development/production modes?

How is this all done and do I need any additonial information?

Bare in mind I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2 version and not 4.0

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :authentication => :plain,
    :address => "smtp.gamil.com",
    :port => 587,
    :domain => Rails.application.secrets.domain,
    :user_name =>Rails.application.secrets.username,
    :password => Rails.application.secrets.password
  }
```

Write in secret.yml:

```
development:
   domain: <%= ENV Domain_you_want %>,
   user_name: <%= ENV  user_name_you_want %>,
   password: <%= ENV  password %>
```

Comment: The `secret.yml` config was [added in Rails 4.1](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html#config-secrets-yml) so this won't work under Rails 3.2.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way of protecting your sensitive information when configuring Rails is to use the **shell environment variables**. In the given environment config file, use the `ENV` hash to access the shell environment variables:

```
# e.g. config/environment/production.rb
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: "smtp.gmail.com",
  port: 587,
  domain: "example.com",
  authentication: "plain",
  enable_starttls_auto: true,
  user_name: ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"],
  password: ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"]
}
```

Then you have to define the env. variables somewhere. This can be done in the `~/.bashrc` file of the user under which you run Rails (the file will be different if you use other shell than bash):

```
# ~/.bashrc
export GMAIL_USERNAME="myname@gmail.com"
# etc...
```

Then relogin to the console and try start up Rails and it should get the correct info from the shell variables. Take a look at [this guide](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-environment-variables.html) for more info. See also the [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/configuring.html#configuring-action-mailer) for all mail configuration options.